# Can Apache restrict access based on a Tomcat webapp's Spring SecurityContext?

Tags: java, apache, web-applications, tomcat, spring-security

We have a tomcat webapp which provides webservices which are protected using Spring Security. The client makes a call to a specific authenticationService method which we wrote to authenticate them and create an authToken which is then used to register them with Spring Security as so:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( authToken )
```

That's all fine and good. However, we also have the requirement that authenticated users be able to access static content which is served by Apache (httpd) on the same server. Is there a way to enforce the requirement that the user has been authenticated (by Java/Spring) before they can download the static content? It seems like Apache and Tomcat would have to somehow share the SecurityContext.

OR - alternatively it seems like Tomcat could serve the static content itself since it already has access to the SecurityContext. If that is the best solution, could anyone provide a pointer to how we would get tomcat to do that (serve static content after checking that the user has been authenticated).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Tomcat is going to have to serve the static content.

[mvc:resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources) can be helpful here.   After that is set up protect those mappings using the standard intercept-url configuration.